# Measurability of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

We know that if $f$ is a continuous function between two topology space $X$ and $Y$ then $f$ is *Borel* measurable. And in other hand we have that composition of two measurable function is measurable and every *Borel* measurable function is *Lebesgue* measurable. So could we say composition of two continuous functions is *Lebesgue* measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition of two continuous functions is continuous, thus Borel measurable, thus Lebesgue measurable.